How to bind [limit] textyankpost to '*' special register [clipboard]
I've tried a lot of things, but basically event.regname is `` for "*y
autocmd textyankpost * 
   if v:event.regname =~ '[8+*]'
      call system('win32yank.exe -i --crlf', @")
   endif

In desperation I've tried doing it the long way,
    nnoremap <silent> <expr> y YankToClipboard('y', v:register)
    nnoremap <silent> <expr> Y YankToClipboard('Y', v:register)


    function! YankToClipboard(command, register)
        if a:register !~ '[+*]' " || has('xterm_clipboard') || has('gui_running')
            " Just return the original command if the clipboard is accessible
            " or it's not a register that should be handled by xsel
            return a:command
        endif

        if a:register == '+'
            " xwindows (no idea what the correct command is)
            return "<Esc>:r !xsel -bo<CR>"
        else
            return "Jump around"
        endif
    endfunction

But this doesn't appear to trigger for "*y either.
Note:
set clipboard=

I'm not interested in any solution involving setting clipboard to 'unnamed' and having the regular yank mess with my clipboard.  Also, Windows 11 based solutions are of no help.

Is this Vim or Neovim?

Here, the following autocommand prints the expected * when I do "*yy with set clipboard= but it prints an empty string with set clipboard=unnamed (my usual value): autocmd! textyankpost * echom v:event.regname. Note that I need to yank to the unnamed register with ""yy to get a ", yy only prints an empty string so my understanding is that one needs to use a register explicitly for v:event.regname to really be useful. So, well… it looks like I have the opposite behavior. Weird.

Of note: your autocommand is missing line continuation \\s. Sourcing those lines "as-is" triggers a bunch of errors and doesn't add the desired autocommand.

@romainl ahh, sorry, they're one line in my .vimrc, i just wrapped them for the post without thinking about it hard enough.

@D.BenKnoble if it was neovim, i would have tagged it thus.  the only reason it's not tagged #vim is that its disallowed :)

@romainl with clipboard=unamed the behavior of "*yy is to yank to the "normal" (i guess it's called unnamed) yanking register, as if you had just hit yy.  All the sucessful solutions for wsl & vim clipboard integration do that, but having my clipboard overwritten everything I yank something is very anti-productive.  not to mention that if you do a visual selection before pasting, the visual selection becomes the clipboard and is then repasted.
